# OnPropertyChanged does not compile

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to binding the content of a label in xaml to a public variable in C# behind. When never the value gets set from the UI, it should trigger the value in the C#.

This VS2008 C# + WPF

However, it does not compile, and it says:

error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for

> 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> error CS1503: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs'

Here is some code

C# code

```
 private bool _isLogOn;

        public  bool IjmFinished
        {
            get 
            {
               // return _fl.ProcessFinished;

                return _isLogOn;
            }
            set 
            {
                _isLogOn = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("IjmFinished");
            }
        }
```

xaml

```
 <Label Margin="120,0,0,82" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="{Binding Path = IjmFinished, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IjmFinishedStatusConverter}}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" />
```

If I uncomment out `OnPropertyChanged("IjmFinished");` it can compile. I am wondering where I did wrong, and how I should change it? Thanks.

Comment: remove that stuff from code behind a create a proper ViewModel and all your problems will magically disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're calling a method in your class that is meant to handle a Dependency Property change.  Instead, you need to raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImFinished"));
```

---

Note that typically you will write a helper method for this in your base view-model class, which looks something like this:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var evt = PropertyChanged;   // create local copy in case the reference is replaced
    if (evt != null)             // check if there are any subscribers
        evt (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

That way you can use simply `RaisePropertyChanged("ImFinished")`.

---

One final note: C# version 5 has a new attribute [`CallerMemberName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows the `RaisePropertyChanged` method to get the calling property's name:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
{
    var evt = PropertyChanged;   // create local copy in case the reference is replaced
    if (evt != null)             // check if there are any subscribers
        evt (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

This saves you from the use of magic strings to specify the property name -- just call `RaisePropertyChanged()` from the property setter.